# Trigger Task Status Icon

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, javascript, tasks

I have a plugin that starts a task and subtasks from a CP widget AJAX call. The tasks are running without a hitch, but for some reason on production, the icon does not appear when the tasks start running unless I refresh the page.

On my local dev site (MAMP), the task icon appears as soon as the code below is called.

I am using this code to start the pending tasks I created:

```
Craft.cp.runPendingTasks();
```

Any ideas? Is there a different JS command I should be using?

Comment: I've seen that on some setups with gzip compression enabled (either at the Apache level or at the PHP level). Might be worth checking.

Comment: Yup, it looks like that is the case. Any thoughts on getting around it? It isn't imperative that the circle displays, but the visual feedback is nice.

Comment: We've spent a ton of time looking into it and it comes down to the fact that PHP sucks. Workaround is to set http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#runTasksAutomatically to false and setup an external cron job to trigger tasks.

Answer (score 6):

I use this to force the task icon to show up immediately:

```
Craft.cp.setRunningTaskInfo({
    "id": "task ID",
    "level": "0",
    "description": "description",
    "status": "running",
    "progress": 0
});
Craft.cp.trackTaskProgress();
```